# Change a list of DataFrame object columns into categories with keeping their names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of Python Pandas DataFrame columns in objects. I am seeking the most parsimonious method (shortest) code to convert them into 'category' types without changing their names.  Currently, I can do this only one by one:

```
df.var_missvent = df.var_missvent.astype('category')
```

The list of columns is obtained by this short code.  This is all the columns which contain the string 'var_'

```
list(df[[x for x in list(df) if 'var_' in x]])
```

Thank you - 
Markos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first filter all columns [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) `var_1` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var_a': [0, 4, 0, 4, 4],
                   'var_b': [5, 10, 10, 5, 5], 
                   'b': [5, 10, 10, 5, 5]})

print (df)
    b  var_a  var_b
0   5      0      5
1  10      4     10
2  10      0     10
3   5      4      5
4   5      4      5

print (df.dtypes)
b        int64
var_a    int64
var_b    int64
dtype: object

print (df.columns.str.contains('var_'))
[False  True  True]

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('var_')]
print (cols)
Index(['var_a', 'var_b'], dtype='object')

df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype('category'))

print (df.dtypes)
b           int64
var_a    category
var_b    category
dtype: object
```

This is nicer, but now not implemented:

```
df[cols] = df[cols].astype('category')
```

> NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time